# require() equivalent if import { Something } from 'somewhere'

Tags: javascript, reactjs, import, ecmascript-6, require

I came into situation where I need to use `require()` instead of es6 `import`.

At the moment my import looks like this:
`import { Footer } from 'LoginComponents'`

LoginComponents has default export of `Content` and additional exports like `Footer`. I need to structure a require statement that solely gets Footer I've tried `require('LoginComponents').Footer`, apparently that is not valid.

This is Footer export:

```
export const Footer = () => (
  <footer>Hello World</footer>
);
```

Comment: what is the error that you get and is loginComponents created by you or it is a npm package

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you're accidentally trying to require a package instead of a local file

```
// require LoginComponents package
const Footer = require('LoginComponents').Footer

// require LoginComponent.js local file
const Footer = require('./LoginComponents').Footer
```

Either way, there is nothing wrong with `require(path).property` — remember `require` is just a normal function with a normal return value (an object), so there's nothing magical going on with it. Accessing a property of its return value is perfectly fine.

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to require a package then you can directly call the package name inside require.Else you need to give path to the file.

```
//if it is package
var Footer = require('LoginComponents').Footer;
//else
var Footer = require('path to login component/LoginComponents').Footer
```

Require is just a function and will return the contents as objects hence we can access the properties usng '.'